# Populating Values Into A Class

Tags: c#, class

I have a XML with me as shown below

```
<Country>
  <Name>Countryname</Name>
  <Continent>ContinentName</Continent>
  <Zone>TimeZone</Zone>
  <India>
    <State>
      <StateName>nameoftheState</StateName>
      <StateCode>codeofthestate</StateCode>
    </State>
  </India>
</Country>
```

This XML has to be populated into a class whose structure is as given below

```
 public class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public India IndiaInfo { get; set; }

    }

   public class India
    {
        public List<State> StateInfo{get; set;}
    }

    public class State
    {
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        public string StateCode { get; set; }
    }
```

DeSerializng the XML to an object is not an option as this XML will pass through another layer which will parse the XML and take out individual elements needed the fill the class.I have written the code to take those values and fill the object as shown below

```
public void PopulateCountry(string name, string Asia , string GMT , string AbcState, string RichState)
    {
        Country objCountry = new Country();
        objCountry.Continent = Asia;
        objCountry.Name = name;
        objCountry.Zone = GMT;

        **India objIndia = new India();
        objIndia.StateInfo = new List<State>;
        State objState = new State();
        objState.StateCode = AbcState;
        objState.StateName = RichState;
        objIndia.StateInfo.Add(objState);
        objCountry.IndiaInfo = objIndia;**



    }
```

In the above method to populate the object of class Country i have taken a brute force approach and put the values in the class and the code is giving results too . However this code is not following some of the best practices and can be further enhanced /rewritten especially the one in Bold. Can someone point out the things/features/practices of C# i am missing .

Comment: Are you looking for [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387050.aspx)?

Comment: *DeSerializng the XML to an object is not an option as this XML will pass through another layer which will parse the XML and take out individual elements needed the fill the class.* Why? this doesn't sound quite right. Why parse *"by hand"* when you can leverage the mechanisms provided by the framework to help you avoid these type of situations?

Comment: DeSerializing the XML can solve the problem. what my aim was to understand how the classes as above can be instantiated and used if we ever have such a situation. I hope this solves the concern. There is nothing here against Deserializing

Comment: @Corak My question was on the class design aspect in the function populatecountry. how the class country can be instantiated correctly. However i'll take a look into the XML to linq

Comment: Then your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: This is a question for http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69533/populating-values-into-a-c-object . I got my answer from this link . Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69533/populating-values-into-a-c-object

I was actually after the problems with the standards followed in the code/example posted in the question and could solve the same on the codereview stackexchange. Thanks for all the help and pointing out the right forum